# how to call methods within a class which is in a controller extension class?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I am trying to write a test class for a controller extension. This controller extension has another class in it . And this class has a few methods.

```
public class Extension_Account
{
    public Extension_Account(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
      public class Class1
      {
       public Class1()
       {
        / * code here*/
        }
        public String getMethod()
        {
         /* code here */
          }
       }
    }
}
```

How can i access the method getMethod in my test class?

In my test class i am able to access the contructor for Class1 but not sure how to get to the other method

```
public with sharing class TestExtension_Account

{
    static testMethod void TestPrint() 
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        //a.Name='Test Account';
        a.FirstName='TestFirst Name';
        a.LastName='Test Last Name';
        a.BillingStreet='Test billing Street';
        a.BillingCity='Test Billing City';
        a.BillingState='Test Billing State';
        a.BillingCountry='Test Billing country';
        a.BillingPostalCode='Test PostCode';
        insert a;



        PageReference pageRef = Page.printaddressaccount;
        pageRef .getParameters().put('id',a.id);
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);
        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(a); 
        Extension_Account ae = new Extension_Account(controller);
        ae.getClass1();
        ae.getMethod()// gives a compiler error Method does not exist or incorrect signature
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your extension class has a getClass1() method that returns an instance of Class1, then you can access the methods from that instance, e.g. `ae.getClass1().getMethod()`;